# Linus and Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

My friend to me that Linus Torvalds uses fedora to compile the kernel. Why does he prefer fedora over any other distribution (ex. Ubuntu)?

Comment: He uses opensuse.

Comment: Do either of you have a reputable source for that? (@tkbx)

Comment: @Kevin his google+ feed.

Comment: @Kevin, Linus has said a few times he uses (or perhaps better, flamed against) Fedora.

Comment: The distribution used to develop kernel-level stuff is mostly irrelevant, they are all built on the same basic software packages. All that matters is that the tools provided are new enough for what you want to do. For userland packages, particularly desktop-environment centric ones, the environment is somewhat more imnportant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of us have our reasons for which OS we use. Many of us move between Linux distributions. Also many use different distributions for different systems at the same time, and I personally use multiple Gnu/Linuxes and several Unixes at any one time.

I cannot comment on what distribution Linus uses, but I suspect that it's not just one distro for every system he uses/administers. While the question of which one he uses (at least primarily) might be answerable here, I haven't heard of any indication as to why he might prefer one over another. We're all starting with the same GNU tools and the same kernel.

Comment: OK, you're right, only, to move between Linux distributions is not anything I would recommend to Linux _beginners_. In general, you should not focus on the distribution - time will be lost installing new ones, migrating files, etc. For example, if the beginner is unsatisfied with something, the solution is most often configuration within his current system.

Comment: I must a agree with you Emanuel. Migrating is quite a drama, even to experienced users. I am fortunate enough to have multiple systems to be able to test suitability and learn peculiarities.